# Typescript extends express request object and export it

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, npm

Using typescript, I am looking to extend the Request object from express to add my custom fields.

Following [this source](https://dev.to/kwabenberko/extend-express-s-request-object-with-typescript-declaration-merging-1nn5) I created a `@types/express/index.d.ts` file with this content :

```
import { MyClass } from "../../src/MyClass";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            myField?: MyClass;
        }
    }
}
```

And add in tsconfig.json :

```
"typeRoots": [
  "@types",
  "./node_modules/@types"
],
```

It works fine.
But I am working on an homemade npm module which I install on an other node application.

And I would like to "export" this new Request type in order for the application to be able to use it

```
import { MyClass } from 'mymodule';

app.use((req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    req.myField = new MyClass(); // <= Typescript doesn't know myField in Request
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type definition should be like this:

```
import { MyClass } from "../../src/MyClass";

declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    myField?: MyClass;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did that but this is not enough.
A solution I found is to export the @types folder on my package : ```"files": [/*...*/, "@types/**/*"]```
Then add
```"typeRoots": ["@types", "./node_modules/mymodule/@types"],```
to the tsconfig.json of the application.
But this is not very convenient as the user of my package has to do it.
Could I use a more automatic way ?